# createGenerateClassName in Material UI v5

Tags: material-ui

What's the proper alternative to legacy https://mui.com/styles/api/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator if `@mui/styles` package is not used, and all styles are created via MUI System (sx)?

By default all classes (even on production) are prefixed with `Mui` and `css` which may become a problem if multiple MUI apps are on the same page (Module Federation especially):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://mui.com/guides/classname-generator/, it is the replacement of `createGenerateClassName`.